# Copy files to output directory issue .targets file

Tags: msbuild, .net-5

I am using targets file to generate some files at runtime and copy them from intermediate directory (obj) to bin.

My environment is .Net 5 and corresponding MSBUILD version.

In general my .targets file working, but I have one issue with it:

**when files are generating in intermediate directory, they saving in path like `obj/x64/Debug/...FileName.fx` and exactly this whole path is copying to output in bin folder.
For example, I have my raw files in `Effects/BasicEffect.fx` and I want to keep this structure in output, but it copying to `obj/x64/Debug/Effects/BasicEffect.fxo` instead and final path is: `bin/x64/Debug/obj/x64/Debug/Effects/BasicEffect.fxo`.** And this is what I want to fix

Here is my targets file:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

   <ItemGroup>
      <AvailableItemName Include="Effect"/>
      <!--<AvailableItemName Include="Font"/>-->
   </ItemGroup>
    
   <!-- In Project A -->  
    <UsingTask Architecture="*" TaskName="EffectCompilerTask" AssemblyFile="$(SolutionDir)CompilerTask\bin\Debug\net5.0\CompilerTask.dll"/>
    <UsingTask Architecture="*" TaskName="CompilerDependencyTask" AssemblyFile="$(SolutionDir)CompilerTask\bin\Debug\net5.0\CompilerTask.dll"/>
  
   <!-- 1st PART : When Project A is built, It will generate effectively the files -->
   <!-- Plugs all dependency listing in AssignTargetPathsDependsOn - in order to support generated output to be copied as part of the build  -->
   <PropertyGroup >
      <BuildDependsOn>
         EngineCompileTarget;
         $(BuildDependsOn);
      </BuildDependsOn>


      <IsBuildInDebug>true</IsBuildInDebug>

      <!--By default turn-on debugging on fx files when compiling in debug (no optimize)-->
      <EngineEffectDebugOption Condition="'$(EngineEffectDebugOption)' == ''">$(IsBuildInDebug)</EngineEffectDebugOption>

      <EffectDynamicCompilingOption Condition="'$(EffectDynamicCompilingOption)' == ''">$(IsBuildInDebug)</EffectDynamicCompilingOption>

      <GenerateCsFileFromEffect>false</GenerateCsFileFromEffect>
      <GenerateBinaryFromEffect>true</GenerateBinaryFromEffect>
      <GenerateCsFileFromFont>false</GenerateCsFileFromFont>
      <GenerateBinaryFromFont>true</GenerateBinaryFromFont>
      <CompileFontBitmaps>false</CompileFontBitmaps>
      
   </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="EngineContentAndCompileTarget" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <CompilerDependencyTask
                ProjectDirectory="$(ProjectDir)"
                IntermediateDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)"
                Files="@(Effect)"
        >
            <Output ItemName="EngineContent" TaskParameter="ContentFiles" />
        </CompilerDependencyTask>

        <ItemGroup>
            <!--List Of fx compiled file-->
            <Content Include="@(EngineContent)" KeepMetadata="CopyToOutputDirectory"/>
        </ItemGroup>

    </Target>
    
<!-- Target used to calculate dependency output -->
   <Target Name="EngineCompileTarget" BeforeTargets="Build">
      <EffectCompilerTask
          Files="@(Effect)"
          ProjectDirectory="$(ProjectDir)"
          IntermediateDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)"
        >
         </EffectCompilerTask>
         
      <Message Text="Hello from EngineCompileTarget" Importance="High"></Message>
      <Message Text="EngineCompileTarget @(Content)" Importance="High"></Message>
   </Target>

</Project>
```

And here is my `Directory.buid.targets` file, which I add to the project, which is building the solution.
Here is content of this file:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
      <AssignTargetPathsDependsOn>
         $(AssignTargetPathsDependsOn);
          EngineContentAndCompileTarget;
      </AssignTargetPathsDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
</Project>
```

Could someone please point me what I am missing here to correctly copy my generated files to the output with saving original file structure?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use `XCOPY` to do this. I for example copy an entire Folder into the output directory. But the Folder exists already. I am not sure if it works with generated files.

Under `Properties` ► `Build Events` ► `Post-build event command line` I do this:

```
XCOPY "$(ProjectDir)myFolder" "$(TargetDir)myFolder" /s /i /y
```

[image]

Comment: I think its not an option, because files is generated in intermediate directory and will be copied to output automatically

Comment: Ok, but I'll leave it here. Maybe someone else needs this option.